# Visio Shape Characters FieldFormula not consistent, why?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, visio

It took several hours for me to solve, so I thought this would be good to share.

I need to link data to a shape that contains a specific FieldFormula
which references a specific Section.User.RowName of the Visio ShapeSheet. The problem is, sometimes the formula is not the actual formula but a reference to it. If you don't know to test for a Master the result is confusing.

The solution lies in testing if the target shape is part of a master instance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.mastershape

shape with no master returns: Sheet.5!User.Input1_PointNameLabel
shape with a master returns: Sheet.5!User.Value[###]
The additional .MasterShape. object is required to access the true formula

```
foreach(V.Page pg in doc.Pages) {
               
   foreach(V.Shape sh in pg.Shapes) {

      string styp = sh.CellExists["Prop.ShapeType", 0] != 0 ? sh.Cells["Prop.ShapeType"].ResultStr[VE.cNC] : "";
      if(styp.Contains("Controller") is false) continue;

      foreach(V.Shape sub in sh.Shapes) {
                     
         if(sub.Characters.IsField == 0) continue;

         string ff = "";
         if(sub.MasterShape is null) {
            ff = sub.Characters.FieldFormula;
         } else {
            ff = sub.MasterShape.Characters.FieldFormula;
         }

         if(ff.Contains("_PointNameLabel") is false) continue;
         GM.LogIt(GM.AppLog, $"pg{pg.Index,2:00} {sh.Name} FF={ff}");
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Did not understand what is your question exactly? If you want to get field value (not formula), you should just use Shape.Characters.Text instead

Comment: The formula contains a cell reference that indicates the cell I need, the text does not.